# c# Paste List<MyObj> return null

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard, copy-paste

I'm trying to Copy and Paste part of my list. Unfortunately, when pasting from the clipboard, the condition finds the stored data, but when assigned to the variable it is still equal to null.
This is my code for List and List Item.

```
public class ListCanvasBlocks : List<MyBlock>
{
    public List<MyBlock> MyCopySelectedObj()
    {
        var x = new List<MyBlock>();
        x.AddRange(this.Where(z => z.IsSelected));
        return x;
    }
}
[Serializable]
public class MyBlock
{
    public MyBlock(Rectangle rect, BlocksData.Shape shape,int id)
    {
        Rect = rect;
        Shape = shape;
        Text = BlocksData.Text(Shape);
        ID = id;
    }
    public string Text; 
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; } = false;
    public bool IsLocked = false;
    public int ID{ get; set; }
    public Point PointInput;
    public Point PointOutput1, PointOutput2;
    public Rectangle Rect;         
    public SolidBrush BackColor;
    public Color FontColor;
    public int FontSize;
    public BlocksData.Shape Shape{get;set;}
}
```

and this is what i do when i press ctrl+c/v

```
      public void Copy()
    {
        Clipboard.Clear();
        Clipboard.SetData("ListCanvasBlocks", _canvObj.MyCopySelectedObj());
    }
    public void Paste()
    {
        if (Clipboard.ContainsData("ListCanvasBlocks"))
            {var test = (ListCanvasBlocks)Clipboard.GetData("ListCanvasBlocks");}
    }
```

Condition in Paste method return true but variable test is still null after assigment

[i'm trying use this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032673/clipboard-copying-objects-to-and-from)

[and this and few others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518701/clipboard-gettext-returns-null-empty-string)

BlockData.Shape is enum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment when I tried to individually add variables to the clipboard, it turned out that the problem was `serialization`. The problem was solved in `SolodBrush` because its `attribute is Color`, and only variables without attributes can be serialized.

[There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318702/why-we-cant-serialize-these-objects) i found solution when i found what is real problem

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cut and paste a `ListCanvasBlocks` but the `MyCopySelectedObj()` method returns a `List<MyBlock>`, which is a supertype. The runtime can't automatically cast from a general to specific.

Try changing this:

```
public class ListCanvasBlocks : List<MyBlock>
{
    public ListCanvasBlocks MyCopySelectedObj()
    {
        var x = new ListCanvasBlocks();
        x.AddRange(this.Where(z => z.IsSelected));
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: It took me a while to get that because he said test was null rather than throwing an exception :(  Alternately he can just cast the result of GetData to List<MyBlock>.

Comment: I tried it before but i tried again for sure. Unfortunately, while paste is still assigned null.Worst case is that I can not verify whether the problem is with copying or pasting. I know only that something is in the clipboard format compatible

Comment: I finally found a problem.
The problem is in a SolidBrush variable. When it is copied unfortunately when you paste we get null .Do You know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like MyCopySelectedObj() returns a List of MyBlock which gets assigned to the name "ListCanvasBlocks" on the Copy(), but when you call Paste(), you cast the List in the Clipboard to Object (ListCanvasBlocks). It is inherited from List, but still not object type ListCanvasBlocks.  Try casting directly to List to that var test when you call your Paste().